# Timer: Play very few Minutes a warnsignal for a duration

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to build a "timer". User can define a duration and the interval. So it will start with a warnsignat, then there will be a warnsignal, which peeps every interval and at the end there should be one.
The problem is: it doesn't work.

The audio just plays all the time.

Possible errorsources:

- peep.loop = false does not work
- it does not block.

```
const peepUrl = require('./../../../Assets/peep.mp3');
const peep = new Audio(peepUrl);
peep.loop = false;

_peep = () => {
 peep.play();
    if(this.state.myInterval > 0) {
      setTimeout(() => { 
        peep.play();
      }, 60000*this.state.myInterval);
    }
clearInterval(this.state.myDuration)
peep.play();

}
```

Comment: Where are you setting `this.state.myDuration`, `this.state.myInterval` and `this.state.value`? And how do you trigger the `_peep` function?

Comment: Thanks, corrected the value.

Comment: _peep() is executed through a button: () => this._peep();

Comment: Did you set `this.state.myDuration` anywhere in your code?

Comment: yes, of course.